# Windows volume sliders move but no change in volume

Tags: windows-10, volume-mixer

I have a Dell Inspiron laptop running windows 10.  If I change the windows volume sliders either for the application or the system,then No change in volume occurs , except for the mute when I go to zero volume.  If I use the in application volume control for Netflix and spottify then I can control the volume.  So can anyone suggest anything. In particular I want the dell laptop function keys for volume to work so if there is a way to get the dell laptop keys to control the settings of the application that may be ok.
I have updated every driver and bios update both from windows update and dell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating the sound drivers in device manager can help
Or unistalling them and testing

Comment: I had uninstalled the driver , after updating them already and this did not fix the problem , after a few other attempts at bios updates, etc  I uninstalled the driver , and selected delete the driver files.  Then the problem was fixed so that was using the generic drivers, I then allowed it to download and install the device specific drivers and it stayed working.  So I'm going to accept the answer